# How to publish data from LWC to the components outside managed package?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, event, lightning-events, isv

I have created a standard LWC datatable in a managed package (let's call this managed LWC component as ComponentA) which will be called in a normal non-packaged LWC component(let's call this as ComponentB).

Now I have to publish selected rows (of ComponentA) outside the managed package back to the componentB.

Can anybody guide on how to send data outside managed package? Will simple events will work when the namespaces of the components are different?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, normal events work as you expect across namespaces. There's no difference between firing events within a namespace as across namespaces. Just follow the directions in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/events). The syntax is exactly the same regardless of namespace.